# Issue with `WhenEvent` with dependence in a parameter

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

Here I define the equations:

```
n = 5;
m = 1/n*IdentityMatrix[n];
k = n*SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1 -> -1, {1, 1} -> 
       1, {i_, i_} /; i != n -> 2, {n, n} -> 1}, {n, n}] // Normal;
X = Table[Indexed[x, i], {i, n}];
V = Table[Indexed[v, i], {i, n}];

eqs0 := Thread[m.D[Through[X[t]], {t, 2}] + k.Through[X[t]] == 0];
ics = Thread[Through[X[0]] == -1]~
   Join~(Thread[D[Through[X[t]], {t, 1}] == 1] /. t -> 0);
```

Then solving with `NDSolve` works fine:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
  eqs0~Join~ics~
   Join~{WhenEvent[Indexed[x, {5}][t] == 1, 
     Indexed[x, {5}]'[t] -> -Indexed[x, {5}]'[t]]}, X, {t, 0, 12.34}]
```

However, if I replace `{5}` with `{n}`, or `Evaluate@{n}`, I get the error

> "The function value x5[0.`] == 1 is not True or False when the
>   arguments are"

The issue is that I want the `WhenEvent` to depend on `n`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I get a `NDSolveValue::deqn` error instead.  What is the message name of the error you get?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `NDSolveValue::nbnum1`

Comment: How about: `sol = NDSolveValue[eqs0~Join~ics~Join~{WhenEvent @@ {Indexed[x, {n}][t] == 1, Indexed[x, {n}]'[t] -> -Indexed[x, {n}]'[t]}}, X, {t, 0, 12.34}]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `WhenEvent` is [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), the trick is to get all the instances of `n` inside `WhenEvent` to be evaluated.  I believe this is necessary because variables like `Indexed[x, {5}]` are replaced by values with `ReplaceAll` or something like it.  That means the code that matches `Indexed[x, {5}]` literally will be replaced by its current value, whereas `Indexed[x, {n}]` in the held code `Indexed[x, {n}][t] == 1` does not match `Indexed[x, {5}]` literally; however, when `Indexed[x {n}]` bubbles up to a level where it is evaluated, such as in the message, it appears as `Indexed[x, {5}]`.

Here are a couple of fixes.  The second lets only `n` be evaluated, and probably should be preferred.

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs0, ics,
   WhenEvent @@ {Indexed[x, {n}][t] == 1, 
     Indexed[x, {n}]'[t] -> -Indexed[x, {n}]'[t]}}, X, {t, 0, 12.34}]

sol = NDSolveValue[{eqs0, ics, 
   With[{n = n}, 
    WhenEvent[Indexed[x, {n}][t] == 1, 
     Indexed[x, {n}]'[t] -> -Indexed[x, {n}]'[t]]]}, X, {t, 0, 12.34}]
```

Comment: Would you know what is the advantage of making `WhenEvent` `HoldAll`?

Comment: @anderstood First, you certainly want it to be at least `HoldRest`, since otherwise `Sow` in the second argument would be evaluated only when `NDSolve` is called and never for an event. Second, the last two examples in the docs under Scope > Events (with `AbsoluteTime[]` and `stop` respectively) would not work if the first argument is not held.

Comment: Another possibility is code that would evaluate differently if the variables were symbolic vs. replaced by numeric values. (No good examples at hand, but functions such as `MemberQ` or `PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ` come to mind.) I'm afraid I've thought of no real compelling examples, but OTOH, if it were not `HoldAll`, I'd have to use `WhenEvent[evt[t, x[t],...], action]`, where `evt[..]` is a `NumericQ`-protected function for many events. That seems equally undesirable.